# HTML form text input not posting '0'?

Tags: html, forms, post

I can't seem to find a straight answer for this: I have a HTML form with nothing special going on, just a couple of text inputs, like so

```
<input type="text" name="field" />
```

When posting it, it posts fine, I store the data in a database, no problem. However, when retrieving the form data, I'm seeing nothing stored at all for a field which I filled with '0'. I was expecting to see '0' of course, but instead it was nothing, just empty.
I checked in Safari's dev tools and found out everything I insert into the text field posts just fine, *except* when I've inserted '0', in which case *nothing* gets posted.

I've been searching, I've read some W3 docs, but nothing is telling me why inserting '0' into a plain text input posts empty. I'm betting some of you might have a clue or actually *know* why... and can offer a solution to get the '0' posted without to many tricks.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data and setting it back in the input field? Just <input type="text" name="field" /> is going to show you empty unless its value field is set.

Comment: What back-end language might you be using? Can you post **that** code?

Comment: Works for me with the following code: http://codepad.org/2JozcALa. please show us your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Your replies made it clear to me nothing should be expected to go wrong with the form, but in the backend. This looked fine however, and when Safari was showing an empty entry in the posted fields, I thought it just had to be the form. However, double checking in Firefox got me my zeroes back! They were posted after all. So I dug deeper in the backend and found out one of the classes (PHP, indeed) checks for 'empty', so there you go... Case closed; thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Safari was incorrect here in reporting 'empty' when it should be '0'. Extra checks confirm that the '0' *does* get posted. The real reason why the '0' wasn't stored in the database was because of a check in the backend (PHP):

```
if (!empty($value)) {
    // validate value for storing
}
```

Because '0' is considered 'empty', it wasn't stored. Refactoring the check solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

0 means NULL with PHP. You will need to cast that as a string upon retrieving the input param in order to store it correctly

```
$newVal = (string) $_FORM['field'];
```

Comment: How do you know he is using PHP?